# How to change the position of a Tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My requirement is like I need to display the tooltip only at left side, I don't want it to be get displayed at right side. What are the css changes I need to do to achieve this. Please help me on this issue.

Note : I don't want to use any kind of Plugin, to do changes only in html (title)tooltip.

**Html**

```
<input type='button' class='sam' id='btnSubmit' value ='submit' title='Click here to submit'/>
```

**CSS**

```
.sam{
    width:200px;
    margin-left:120px;
    margin-top:25px;  

}

.sam[title] {
    position:fixed;
top:100px;
left:50px;
}
```

Here I have attached the link that i have tried

[JsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/FYF2m/)

Comment: sam[title] it doesn't be worked.  check out this post, it may be could help you. ---->  http://cbavota.bitbucket.org/css3-tips/

Comment: With the default `title` attribute tooltip, I don't think you can do custom positioning. However we can create custom tooltips like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/FYF2m/1/)

Comment: [**This**](http://jsfiddle.net/FYF2m/2/) is a more updated version which exactly matches your need. If you wish to use this, I will add it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible without a plugin or custom code. You will have to implement a **custom** tooltip using HTML/CSS and dynamically show it on hover.

By the way: Your CSS-Selector `.sam[title]` matches every element which has the class "sam" and any title, to select all element with the title "hello" you would have to use this selector: `.sam[title=hello]`

Comment: Could (as you suggest) write her own css/js, so doesn't need a "plugin" -- but agreed that pure HTML won't do the trick.

Comment: Yes, my explanation is not clear. I updated my answer to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

As Fabio said, it is not possible to change the position of a tooltip. However, I can recommend making your own simply implementing basic JQuery and CSS.

First, make your tooltip in CSS. For example:

```
#tooltipbox {
min-height: 300px;
max-height: 500px;
width: 500px;
background-color:yellow;
opacity: .6
color: red;
position: fixed;
top: 10px;
right: 100px;
}
```

After that, you'll need to put it in HTML using a DIV.

`<div id="tooltipbox">yourcontent</div>`

Next you'll need to make a small jquery script.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function toolTipper(myToolTip, objectHover, fadeInTime,fadeOutTime){
        $(myToolTip).hide();
        $(objectHover).mouseenter(function(){$(myToolTip).show(fadeInTime)};
        $(onjectHover).mouseleave(function(){$(myToolTip).hide(fadeOutTime)};
    }
    toolTipper('#tooltipbox','.objectyouhoverover', 1000, 500)
}
```

Let me break it down for you. You made a div that has your tool tip text positioned where you want, styled however you want. Then in a script, we hide it so that when they hover over your object, that particular tooltip is then shown. When you leave that object, it disappears as should a tooltip should.

The code is rather simple; however to understand what I did, you'll need to understand basic Javascript and Jquery. I made a function with the parameters you'll need to enter for every tool tip you made. Lets say you made a styled word that needs a definition and therefore requires a tooltip. You first attach a class or ID to it which doesn't need to be defined in your CSS document. You just need it there for the script to find it.

In this sentence, **chicken** is bold.

**Chicken** is the object with a unique class of ".chickentooloject".

Next you make a unique tool tip div.

```
<div id="tooltipbox" class="tooltipbox1"> A chicken is a bird. </div>.
```

Why did we do this? So we also have a unique tool tip to be found by the script. The rest is up to the script.

```
toolTipper('.tooltipbox1', '.chickentoolobject', 500, 1000);
```

*The code is untested, but it is simple jquery, so I am positive it'll work. If you're confused, leave a comment and I will help you more.*